# execute process in Perl with options for stopping,resuming,killing using IPC

Tags: perl, process, fork, exe, execution

I almost have no idea of forking. I tried to research, but I couldn't find a simple example of how to do these things. For windows I found a good module and wrote this piece of code, which is doing what I want.

```
   Win32::Process::Create( my $ProcessObj,
    "$jobs{$id}->{path}", "execute job", 0, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, "." )
  || die ErrorReport();
print "Available commands:\n1.Suspend\n2.Resume\n3.Kill\n";
while (1) {
    chomp( my $input = <STDIN> );
    if ( $input eq "1" ) {
        $ProcessObj->Suspend();
    }
    if ( $input eq "2" ) {
        $ProcessObj->Resume();
    }
    if ( $input eq "3" ) {
        print "Returned to main menu.\n";
        $ProcessObj->Kill(0);
        return;
    }
}
```

So my question is if there is a way to do this with forking?
And here is my try for forking:

```
unless ( $pid = fork) {
        unless (fork) {
            exec "$jobs{$id}->{path}";
            die "exec failed!";
        }
        exit 0;
    }
    waitpid($pid, 0);
```

I have a program which is printing Hello world every 3 seconds and I want to pause it, resume it and kill it, if this example will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Forks::Super`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Forks::Super) makes this simple and platform-independent.

```
use Forks::Super;
...
my $pid = fork { exec => $jobs{$id}->{path} };
...
$pid->suspend;
...
$pid->resume;
...
$pid->kill;       # or $pid->kill('TERM'), $pid->kill('QUIT'), etc.
```

Comment: ehh, the installation of the module failed :(

Answer (score 1):

If you must go by hand, the signals to use are `'SIGSTOP'` and `'SIGCONT'`.

A command-line demo

```
perl -wE'
    $pid = fork // die "Cant fork: $!"; 
    if ($pid == 0) { 
        for (1..6) { say "\tkid ..."; sleep 1; }; 
        say "\tKID DONE"; exit; 
    }; 
    sleep 3; 
    kill "STOP", $pid; 
    for (1..2) { say "Parent here!"; sleep 1}; 
    kill "CONT", $pid; 
    wait;    
'
```

prints

```
        kid ...
        kid ...
        kid ...
Parent here!
Parent here!
        kid ...
        kid ...
        kid ...
        KID DONE
```

Then you'd need to implement this in your `STDIN`-driven management.

But I suggest to try to resolve the installation of [Forks::Super](http://search.cpan.org/~mob/Forks-Super-0.84/lib/Forks/Super.pm), from mob's answer.

---

A `STDIN` controlled example.  The forked process and the parent write to a file for a test.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';    
#use IO::Handle;            # needed pre v5.16 (for autoflush)

my $fh_kid;
$SIG{INT} = sub { close $fh_kid; exit 1 };

my $file = 'kidfile.out';
open $fh_kid, '>', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";
$fh_kid->autoflush;

my $pid = fork // die "Can't fork: $!";

if ($pid == 0) {
    $SIG{TERM} = sub { close $fh_kid; exit 1 };
    for (1..20) { 
        say $fh_kid "\tkid, $_"; 
        sleep 1;
    }   
    exit;
}
say "Parent: started $pid";

while (1) {
    chomp (my $input = <STDIN>);
    if (not $input) {
        close $fh_kid; 
        last;
    }   
    if ($input == 1) {
        kill 'STOP', $pid;
        say         "Parent: STOP-ed $pid";
        say $fh_kid "Parent STOP-ed $pid";
    }   
    elsif ($input == 2) {
        say "Parent: CONT the $pid";
        kill 'CONT', $pid;
    }   
    elsif ($input == 3) {
        close $fh_kid;
        kill 'TERM', $pid;
        say "Parent: TERM-ed the $pid";
    }   
}

my $gone = waitpid $pid, 0;

if    ($gone > 0) { say "Child $gone exited with: $?" }
elsif ($gone < 0) { say "No such process ($gone), reaped already?" }
else              { say "Still out there?" }
```

This needs more detail but it does show what kinds of things get involved.

Output (with comments)

```
Parent: started 19628
1                              # entered a few seconds after starting
Parent: STOP-ed 19628
2                              # after waiting for a minute
Parent: CONT the 19628
3                              # after waiting for a few more seconds
Parent: TERM-ed the 19628
^C                             # quit STDIN
```

We allow the kid to print to a file for a few seconds (so a few times) and then `STOP` it (1), then wait for a bit and then `CONT`inue the child (2) and let it print a few more times before killing it (3).

The output `kidfile.out` has a few lines from the child, then a line from the parent, and then a few more lines from the child, confirming that the child was paused, resumed, and stopped.